# Is the ring $\mathbb{R} [x]$ Noetherian?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian

I aim to assess the soundness of my approach. In an exercise, the question is posed regarding whether $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is Noetherian, and my response is negative. To support this, I employ the definition that a ring $R$ is Noetherian if each ascending chain of ideals in $R$ eventually becomes stable.

Considering the family $\{I_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where

$$I_n = \{f\in\mathbb{R}[x] \mid \text{such that } f(a) = 0 \ \forall a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1,...,n\}\}.$$

I can easily demonstrate that $I_n$ is an ideal for all $n\in\mathbb{N} $.

Furthermore, if $f \in I_n$, then $f(a) = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1,...,n\}$, and consequently, $f(a) = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1,...,n, n+1\}$.

This establishes $I_n \subset I_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prompting me to observe the following ascending chain:

$$I_0 \subset I_1 \subset I_2 \subset \cdots. $$

However, this chain does not stabilize, indicating tha $\mathbb{R} [x]$ is not noetherian.

Is my solution correct, or am I missing something? Please provide feedback.

Comment: Please, can you explain whay?

Comment: I am also not completely sure if your $I_n$ exist (I might be wrong). $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ is infinite, thus you can't have polynomials which are vanishing on all of them.

Comment: Each $I_n = 0$. Consider the Taylor expansion of any element. Also, Hilbert's Basis Theorem should help determine an answer to the original question. Alternatively, $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a PID, and are all PID's Noetherian?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean.

Comment: The main point that you are missing, by the way, is the fact that the quotient rings $\mathbb R/I_n$ bear a well-known algebraic structure (just forget the ring multiplication)

Comment: A polynomial with real coefficients of degree $n$ has at most $n$ real roots. Since the elements if $I_n$ vanish at infinitely many points, they must all be the zero polynomial. You correctly argue that $I_n\subseteq I_{n+1}$, but what you'd need to show is $I_n\subsetneq I_{n+1}$. That requires exhibiting a polynomial that is in $I_{n+1}$ but not in $I_n$... and you won't be able to, since $I_n=I_{n+1}=(0)$.

Comment: You seem to have concluded that because your "defining condition" is different, it follows that the ideal are different. But as you see, that is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, suppose $f \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ vanishes at every point outside of a finite set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then, the set of elements of $\mathbb{R}$ which are sent to zero are $f^{-1}(\{0\}) \subset \mathbb{R}$, which is a closed set. Hence, since $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we must have $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \mathbb{R}$, where we view $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as a continuous function. Hence $f$ is the zero function which implies $f$ is the zero polynomial.

Alternatively, any polynomial $f \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ is equal to its Taylor expansion around any point $$f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x - a)^n$$ so if $f$ is uniformly zero on $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$, all of its derivatives would also vanish on $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$, so taylor expanding this polynomial around any point of $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$ would reveal it to be the zero polynomial.

As such, your ascending chain is just the trivial chain $(0) \subset (0) \subset \cdots$ which stabilizes immediately.

In fact, the division algorithm tells us that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a PID. In particular if we had an ascending chain of ideals $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset \cdots$ we would have $I_n = (g_n)$ where $g_n \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and for any $n$, $g_{n + 1}$ divides $g_n$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Must this stabilize?

Comment: Why topology or Taylor? From standard algebraic results, a real polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots, so only the zero polynomial vanishes at infinitely many real points.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much; I've understood it. Since $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ is infinite, and the set $S=\{0,1,\cdots,n\}$ is countable, then $f(x) = 0$ continuously in $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ (i.e., $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$), and thus $f$ is the zero polynomial. And this is a quite similar to the principle of isolated zeros.

Comment: @Daniel, please reply and confirm if I am correct. Polynomials are all analytic, so if a polynomial P is zero in an open set of \mathbb{R} , then it is zero in \mathbb{R} (by the principle of analytic extension). However, if we have a continuous function instead of polynomials, my proof will work (as $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ is not Noetherian). For instance, we can find a continuous function that is not analytic, like $f(x) = x$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and zero elsewhere.

Comment: @Santa-claus Sorry for the delay. This chain of ideals would also be all zero in $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ for similar reasons. $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$ is not only infinite but *dense*, so that any closed set containing it is all of $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, $f^{-1}(0) = \mathbb{R}$ if $f$ is continuous and vanishes on $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$.

Comment: "Yes, I got it, but what if we take $]-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}[$? Will it work?"

Comment: @Santa-claus In this case I think it would work.